# Message Queues and/or daemons on shared hosting

Tags: php, cron, message-queue, daemon

Most of the time it's not possible to have anything like MQs or daemons running on shared hosting.

Considering the scenario:

> A DB gets filled with jobs and I want them to be handled one after
>   another

What are the options?

Is it only just cron and it's 60 second limit? Or that cron hack where you try to do as much in those 60 secs..

Comment: What 60 seconds limit in cron? And also 60 seconds should be enough to trigger a php script. What you do inside that script is up to you, there are many ways to get around a time limit here.

Comment: Cronjobs can only be fired every minute (or am I wrong?) and what I'm looking for is every 4 seconds (or however long the job takes) and then just carry on.

Comment: The cronjob only has to act as a trigger, not more. Typically it is used to trigger some script that takes care to identify the pending jobs and get them processed. Such script can be implemented such that it reacts on new jobs being generated. So you have no real limit left on the processing side. You should _never_ use a cron trigger to directly execute pending jobs. This does not allow any safety precautions against queue pollution and the like.

Comment: Shared hosts are typically structured so you cannot run any long running or permanent tasks, be it via cron or the web server. That's pretty much a necessity to make shared hosting work. Meaning, shared hosts are pretty much an extremely hostile environment for this kind of thing and there's likely no great solution at all. The least bad solution depends on what exactly your host allows and doesn't allow. Typically, if your app is of sufficient complexity to warrant MQs, it probably also warrants is own dedicated server.